# Android app run notification if user has not opened app

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Im trying to run a notification if a user has not opened an app in say 24 hours to encourage them to open it (Similar to duolingo style). Im using Java and I can set a periodic notification using workmanager but it runs while the app is open which is not what I want. I want the notification to run every 24 hours however if the user has opened the app this timer should reset, I've searched for this but can't find what I require exactly

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) for your case. You can, for example, reschedule it in `Application.onCreate()` method to fire in 24 hours after user last launched an app. First you need to cancel previously scheduled alarm using `cancel` method, and then set a new alarm to fire in 24 hours using one of the `set...()` methods available in `AlarmManager` class.